# Accessing other abstract classes without including a reference in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I came across an old code in which there are few projects and each of them having few abstract classes, headers and cpp files. 
Strange thing is in one of the projects a abstract class makes use of a function declared in another abstract classs in the same project. What surprised me was there was no reference made to the other abstract class from the current abstract class and the compiler did not throw any error. 
Only thing I noticed was both files are in namespace.

Can anyone explain how is this possible?

Here are is a sample code of the class which is being referenced

```
#ifndef ClassADef
#define ClassADef

#include <string>

namespace globalNameSpace {
class ClassA {
public:

    virtual ~ClassA() = default;
    virtual std::string method1() const = 0;
};
}
#endif
```

Here is the sample code for the class which references the above class.

```
#ifndef ClassBDef
#define ClassBDef

#include <string>

//I was expecting an include statement which references the above class

namespace globalNameSpace {
class ClassB {
public:
    virtual std::string method2(const ClassA& method1, const bool variable) = 0; 
//I was expecting the compiler to throw an error.
};

}

#endif
```

Comment: Headers are fun. Remember for headers to do anything they have to be included by a file that is being compiled. Headers are effectively pasted into the including file, making one big file that is compiled. Likely whatever file included these two headers included ClassADef before it included ClassBDef, declaring `ClassA` before `ClassB` needed it. As you have realized this is a bad idea. One it causes confusion (Dude, where's my include?) and two if someone changes the include order, for example including another file that includes ClassBDef before including ClassADef you could get an error.

Comment: ^^^ Without a forward decl of `ClassA`, this cannot possibly compile without the consuming cpp file including `ClassA.h` (somehow, not necessarily direct inclusion) before including `ClassB.h`. That's known as an implicit include-order dependency, and it's a *terrible* practice, so the one thing you should learn in looking at this is don't be the person that writes like this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Dimitry [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56160253/8285537) helped me figure it out. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the forward declaration or explicit include there could be another CPP file that includes both headers in the correct order:

```
#include <ClassADef>
#include <ClassBDef>
```

That is a bad practice, but that could explain the correctness of the code you provided.

Comment: Yeah in one of the child classes which inherits the abstract class ClassB. They have added include "ClassA.h" and "ClassB.h". Also it did not recognize when the order was changed. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The use of reference to ClassA seems valid, as long as ClassA is forward declared before the definition of ClassB.

Comment: Sure. Except that's not in the header the OP posted. I see no forward decl of `ClassA`, and I'm fairly confident if the OP saw one they wouldn't be here.

Comment: `ClassB` Doesn't have to be forward declared. Simply including ClassA's header at any point before ClassB's header, no matter how strange or circuitous the route to the inclusion, will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Dimitry [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56160253/8285537) helped me figure it out. Thanks for your time.